# C++ Parent Class that calls method in Child Class, that call Parent Class Method

Tags: c++, function, oop, inheritance, parent-child

if I have this Code for example:

```
class ChildOne
{
    ChildOneFunc()
    {
        Parent::ParentFunction();
    }
    CallNeighbour()
    {
        ChildTwoFunc();
    }
};

class ChildTwo
{
    ChildTwoFunc();
};

class Parent : public virtual ChildOne, public virtual ChildTwo
{
    Parent() //Constructor
    {
        ChildOneFunc();
    }
    ParentFunction();
};
```

How is it possible to do this?
Because in Child two the Class Parent isnt defined and forward declaration
gives me only errors.

Second question:

How could i call the CildOneFunction() from Childtwo?

Comment: Usually, the derived class is referred to as 'child' and the base class as 'parent'. You turn this upside down, which really confusing.

Comment: Oh, i thought i inherit the child classes to the parent class with:

class Parent : public virtual ChildOne, public virtual ChildTwo

isnt that the case?

Comment: You never inherit *to* (not in real life and not in C++), but always *from* (inherit='erben' in German, not 'vererben')

Comment: @PeterLustig, in your example of code the `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` are not linked, while `Parent` is derived class for both of them. Say, `ChildOne` is "Mechanism" and `ChildTwo` is "Wheeled", `Parent` can be "Car"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the first via static or dynamic polymorphism. Avoiding your confusing nomenclature of 'parent' and 'child', here is a possibility using dynamic polymorphism:

```
struct base /* aka ChildOne */
{
  virtual void func() const = 0;
  void basefunc() { func(); }
};

struct derived /* aka Parent */
: base
{
  void func() const override;
};
```

Here, the `derived` class has a *is-a* relationship to `base`: a object of type `derived` *is also an object* of type `base`. Dynamic polymorphism is implemented via virtual tables, which incurs some (small) run-time overhead. This can be avoided using static polymorphism via CRTP:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct base 
{
  void basefunc() { static_cast<const Derived>(this)->func(); }
};

struct derived
: base<derived>
{
  void func() const;
};
```

which does not need a virtual table look up, since no `virtual` functions are used.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you cannot do it in general case, but you can add a check using `dynamic_cast`.

It's a bit confusing that you use `Parent` name to define derived class, and `Child` to define the base class, but I will use your terminology.
The `ChildTwo` class is not linked with `ChildOne` with inheritance, so in any method of `ClassTwo` you have just a `ClassTwo` object which may not implement `ChildOne` methods. But you can check it using `dynamic_cast`:

```
ChildTwoFunc()
{
    auto thisAsChildOne = dynamic_cast<ChildOne*>(this);
    if (thisAsChildOne != nullptr)
    {
        thisAsChildOne->ChildOneFunc();
    }
}
```

Here we first try to convert `this` to pointer to `ChildOne` with all necessary run-time checks. If `this` is not object of any class derived from `ChildOne` (in your example, if `this` is not `Parent`) this `dynamic_cast` will return `nullptr`. If the cast was successful, we call the function.

For an arbitrary `ChildTwo` you can force compiler to call this function using `reinterpret_cast`, but this is **HIGHLY UNSAFE**.

For more information about `dynamic_cast` you can read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)

Comment: Don't do this. Frequent use of `dynamic_cast` is the hall mark of poor programming design and style.

Comment: @Walter, in author's code we have two classes `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` which are not linked by inheritance, but he wants to call methods of one class from another. Of course, this is a strong sign of bad design, but how can you call these methods with no `dynamic_cast`? I mean, in exactly this classes structure?